# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined in mocha

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I am doing a read test in mongodb using mocha, mongoose and nodemon. These 2 errors come up when i run the test in node:
[image]

This is my describe block:

```
//All read tests
describe("Read tests", () => {
    let reader;
    beforeEach((done) => {
        reader = Student({name : "Reader"});
        reader.save().then(() => {
            done();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error", error);
        });
    });
    it("Read a user: Reader", (done) => {
        Student.find({name : "Reader"}).then((students) => {
            //id is a BSON value
            assert(reader._id.toString() === students._id.toString());
            done();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error", error);
        });
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?